# Altering VBA Access code to merge powerpoint presentations instead of word documents

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, powerpoint

I have some code that combines multiple word documents together, however, I would like to alter it to combine powerpoint presentations together.

I'm new to programming and struggle to find the correct sections to change or the correct 'vocab' to use.

If you could help that would be really useful.

My code is

```
'Code to merge selected documents together
Sub MergeDocs(strInFullNames() As String, strOutFullName As String, 
intNoOfFiles As Integer)
   Dim wdApp As word.Application
   Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
   Dim outDoc As Word.Document
   Dim w As Integer
   Dim bNewInstance As Boolean


'Try to use already running instance of Word
On Error Resume Next
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "word.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

If wdApp Is Nothing Then
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("word.application")
    bNewInstance = True
End If

Set outDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add

'For w = 0 To UBound(strInFullNames)
    If w > 0 Then
 '       outDoc.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Range.InsertBreak wdSectionBreakNextPage
  '  End If
   ' Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(strInFullNames(w))
   ' objSelection.PasteAndFormat
    'wdDoc.Range.Copy
     'wdDoc.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
    'outDoc.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Range.Paste
'Next w

outDoc.SaveAs strOutFullName



'only close Word application if instance created for this macro
If bNewInstance Then
    wdApp.Quit
End If
```

MsgBox "Word Document Created"
End Sub

Thanks

Comment: Hallo, 
First you will have to open "powerpoint.Application" instead of "word.Application" offcourse

Comment: Because the two tasks involve different sets of objects -- Word objects vs PowerPoint objects -- I don't think there is much point in starting with code that does one task for Word documents and try to convert it into code that does another task for presentations. Instead, consider the problem on its own merits -- if you had to merge the presentations by hand, how would you do it? 1) Open the PowerPoint application, 2) open the destination presentation 3) open the source presentation 4) copy slides from the source to the destination 5) save the destination presentation. The next step is to ...

Comment: ... figure out the corresponding code for each step. Then, if you get stuck on a given step, and you've done some research without success, it's more appropriate to ask on StackOverflow something like _"How do I open the PowerPoint application from VBA?"_.

Comment: And to add, StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please attempt such a PowerPoint merge and come back with specific issues/errors you need help resolving.

Comment: Thank you @ZevSpitz. even just helping me break down the problem has helped clarify what I need to work on and makes the task easier.

Comment: Sorry @Parfait if it seemed like I was expecting code written for me. I was not. I just wanted some guidance on where to start or where to go looking for good tutorials or lists of powerpoint related vocab.

Comment: @Fiona The [PowerPoint VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/vba-powerpoint) section on MSDN has the documentation of the [PowerPoint object model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/object-model-powerpoint-vba-reference) -- the various object types and their properties and methods, that can be used to program the PowerPoint application. (N.B. The **Concepts** and **How To** have a lot of topics that are more related to general VBA development; most of it is irrelevant to the type of things you want to do.)